# Complex navigation stack in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have a complex navigation problem that I was hoping someone may be able to give me some insight as to the best way to approach this problem.  I've been Googling and have found multiple different suggestions for similar problems, but none of them seem to quite nail down my problem.

I have a UITabBarController.  Each tab is set up with it's own Navigation stack, as it should have.

One of those tabs uses a UISegmentedControl with three segments.  Each of those segments needs to have its own view controller and navigation stack, independent of one another and of the navigation stack that the tab bar controller controls for its tab.  Basically, it needs to work like a UITabBarController within a tab of a UITabBarController, but display the tabs as a UISegmentedControl.

Also, when at the root controller of each tab, the navigation stack should be the stack that it came in from, so that it pops out to the table view that it came in from.

I hit a snag and feel like I would have to have some brutal hack to go forward, no matter what I try.  Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

I would strongly prefer to be able to handle the connections in Storyboard, so as to keep my storyboard nice and pretty, but if it must be done in code, I can do that too.

### Edit

I have something of a solution. In the base class:

```
    private func show(segment: SelectedSegment) {
    var equipmentStoryboard: UIStoryboard!
    switch segment {
    case .SelEquipment:
        equipmentStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EquipmentDetailEquipmentSegment", bundle: nil)
    case .SelHistory:
        equipmentStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EquipmentDetailHistorySegment", bundle: nil)
    case .SelPlans:
        equipmentStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EquipmentDetailPlansSegment", bundle: nil)
    }

    if let newSegmentController = equipmentStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: segment.getSegmentIdentifier()) as? EquipmentDetailSegmentsViewController {
        var controllerStack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
        controllerStack?.removeLast()
        controllerStack?.append(newSegmentController)
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllerStack!, animated: false)
    }
}
@IBAction func didTapSegmentedControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let newSelectedSegment = SelectedSegment(rawValue: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

    self.show(segment: newSelectedSegment!)
}
```

I'm not happy about it though.  I'd like to:

1. Not have to re-instantiate each controller every time the segment is tapped.
2. Be able to storyboard it (may not be possible without an actual UISegmentedControlController or something like that)

Comment: Please see edited question for my solution.  Opinions on this approach are welcome.

Comment: If your edit is a working answer, would you roll that edit back and post it as an answer proper below? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually not the solution.  I tried so many different things and had problems no matter what I tried.  I ended up re-instantiating every view controller that should be shown, every time a segment is tapped again.  I did stay with the navigation stack manipulation, but I still feel strongly that there should be a more elegant way of doing this.  If there's something that somehow takes the segmented control and makes it behave like a tab bar controller, that would be excellent.  I'd like to leave this open for possible further answers, if I may.

Comment: Tried using container views per view to be displayed (isHidden swapping) but that didn't work because the controllers weren't on any navigation stack and adding a navigation controller to those controllers caused an embedded navigation bar (funny, I thought).

Comment: I tried having an array of controllers that was passed between the three controllers so that each controller wasn't re-instantiated every time a segment would be tapped but that didn't work because I ran into an issue with the segment controller not showing the correct button highlighted (probably because viewDidLoad wasn't called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the right solution to the problem.  I had to write a custom system.  I'm going to come back to this and work on it at some point so that I can provide a github project with the API that would provide this functionality to anyone publicly.

Basically, the system does this:

- Scrollable Segmented Control that is expandable to as many segments as desired.
- A "SegmentNavigationController", which is a UIViewController because it contains views that are swapped to, brought to front, shown, (and rest hidden) when tapping on the respective segment.

  - Each segment has it's own navigation stack, which is simply an array of the view controllers that control the views in the current segment.
  - Custom animation takes place when pushing and popping an item to/from the navigation stack, to make it appear to be a natural iOS controller.  The segmented control stays in place, while the new view animates in.
  - Navigation is retained, so that when switching between segments, you can resume where left off when tapping a different segment.
- Utilizes the Clean Swift Architecture: http://clean-swift.com

I'm posting this as an answer because **a custom system was the best solution** after days of deliberation on the subject.

This is of course also a preliminary to possibly expanding this system to something useful and reusable.